# Not all Linux installations displayed in GRUB. How to fix?

Tags: boot, grub2

For testing purposes I installed Natty. During the installation I chose to install it next to my "safe" installation of 10.10.

This installation also still seems to be there, but I can not manage to boot it from GRUB anymore. It is simply not shown. Booting Natty works like charm, though.

How do I get it to appear again, so I can boot that installation?

*`sudo update-grub` output*

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-1-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-1-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.37-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.37-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I had the same problem. You know how I fixed it? Yes, a painful method - By Hand.

Let me explain you how I did it. I needed to add this entry to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Take a backup of the file before you go ahead

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --> class gnu --class os {

recordfail

insmod part_msdos

insmod reiserfs

set root='(hd0,msdos7)'

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set ada5fcfd-84b7-4ffa-9c52-db45d17518a7

linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic root=UUID=ada5fcfd-84b7-4ffa-9c52-db45d17518a7 ro   quiet splash
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic

}
```

The menuentry name can be `'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-25-generic'` or whatever you choose to be.

Change the `set root='(hd0,msdos7)'` to `set root='(hd0,msdosx)'` and `x` represents the partition no of the drive

`insmod reiserfs` can be changed to `insmod ext4` or the filesystem you choose (info from the links which I googled up just now). Since I have all my / parititons as reiserfs so I did not need to change this.

`ada5fcfd-84b7-4ffa-9c52-db45d17518a7` in the last two lines can be replaced by the partition UUID. You can get the partition UUID by running the command

> ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

`/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic` is a file contained in the /boot folder in the parition where your ubuntu is installed. Yours can be a different version number. The file should start with vmlinuz

Just like `/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic` same goes for `/boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic`

After booting and selecting this option, I found that there was an error. Leaving it for a few seconds made it continue and I am now typing from the installation entry I added in grub list.

Footnote: GRUB2 is still a mystery. Grub Legacy had easier config files

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running "sudo update-grub" to see if it detects the other system?

Comment: Yap, did that, did not help. It only displays the images as shown during boot as well.

Comment: Well, you can try something else.  Download the "Super Grub2 Disk" (http://www.supergrubdisk.org)

Comment: Download the "Super Grub2 Disk" (http://www.supergrubdisk.org). Boot from it, let it find your existing systems and log into your 10.10 install.  From within the Maverick environment run update-grub again to see if it finds the 11.04 kernels, if it does, then run sudo grub-install /dev/sdx to use Maverick's grub2.  If it doesn't find Natty... well, at least you have your "safe" 10.10 back!  Another cuestion: when you boot into 11.04, can you "see" the 10.10 filesystem?  It's a good idea to run sudo fdisk -l just to be sure you didn't overwrite your 10.10